# BitmapFactory.decodeResource Returns Null for HTC One V (primoc) phone

Tags: android

I have the following code retrieving a bmp file from the res folder.  I have all of the images stored in the drawable-hdpi folder and it's not working on the HTC One V (primoc). Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
```

Here is the logcat

```
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1105)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:554)
at scahagamecenter.com.LeadersListView.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(LeadersListView.java:128)
at scahagamecenter.com.LeadersListView.getView(LeadersListView.java:110)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2075)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1476)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1339)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2145)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1227)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2695)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please provide a more succinct question; I'm really not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: is there somethings specific with android 4.0.1 that is used on the htc phone that would cause the code to not find the resource.  with htc do i need to copy all of my resource files to all the different drawable folders?  I have noticed in 4.3 if i put the files in the hdpi folder the resource files are found.